# Kotlin drawable Reference: I want to construct a String with the name of the drawable and then use it as resource reference

Tags: android, string, kotlin, imageview, resources

I have a little function to set an imageResource depending on delivered parameters.

```
private fun setImageView(image: ImageView, type: String, value: Int) {
    var nameString = "ic_"
    when (image.tag) {
        "tagone" -> nameString += "tagone_"
        "tagtwo" -> nameString += "tagtwo_"
        "tagthree" -> nameString += "tagthree_"
    }
    when (value) {
        0 -> nameString += "0"
        1 -> nameString += "1"
        2 -> nameString += "2"
        3 -> nameString += "3"
        else -> nameString = nameString
    }
    image.setImageResource(R.drawable.${nameString})
}
```

Can someone tell me a way to use my constructed String as reference for the resource? Is it possible at all?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a combination of `resources.getIdentifier()` and `setImageResource`.

See the Android docs for usage of [getIdentifier](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources#getIdentifier(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String))

In your example you should be able to use something like:

```
int drawableId = getResources().getIdentifier(nameString, "drawable", getApplicationContext().getPackageName());
image.setImageResource(drawableId)
```

**Note**: be aware that lint won't be able to recognize usage of the resources and will mark them as unused! Also you won't have any compile time checks so make sure you're not missing any resources.

Comment: Thanks a lot. This was very useful and works pretty good.I had to manually insert the package name because I couldn't use your expression. But this is no problem at all.

Comment: If you want to retrieve the package name dynamically you need to retrieve the context from somewhere. You could even get it from the ImageView in your case, it's not very elegant but it prevents hardcoding the packagename.